# image area select using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js . I have requirement like , our app will have one browse button through which we can browse and preview a image.User should be able to select an rectangular area from that image and should be able to get the coordinates of rectangular area. Please suggest me if there is any plugin available in angular to achieve this

Comment: Did you even try searching?

Comment: Yes I tried . Iam able to implement till file browsing but Iam not able to select and  get the coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a repository on github named [cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) and [angular wrapper](https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper) of it. It is very easy to find js libraries nowadays. just google it like

> "my purpose" + js library